# Reactjs and Django Independent Functionality

Tags: django, reactjs

I am new to django and reactjs and I want to ask if it is possible to make an application that have the following requirements:

- > "Reactjs only care of front-end". No need to import the scripts of reactjs to the templates of Django. Most of the tutorial I read are importing the bundles of Reactjs into the Django templates.
- > "Django handles everything on backend". Django only wait for any request and return response.

If you know any blog, tutorials please include it on your answers.

Thank you very much!

Comment: How will your frontend pages be loaded?

Comment: Yes this is possible, check out [Reconciling Django and React](https://hackernoon.com/reconciling-djangos-mvc-templates-with-react-components-3aa986cf510a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite easily: you can build and serve your frontend as static (html/js/etc) files, and have the js code issuing ajax requests to a django app only exposing a Rest API. You don't even need both parts to live on the same server FWIW.

Note that this isn't anything special to Django nor ReactJS - you could do the exact same thing with Angular + Rails or just any (frontend js stuff / backend techno) combination, and even with raw javascript and plain PHP or CGI.